# How stop the process of submitting a comment if a fields are empty?

Tags: comments

How stop the process of submitting a comment if a field is empty?

```
<form action="http://localhost/test/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form">
    <p class="comment-form-title">
        <label for="pmg_comment_title">Review Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="review_title" id="pmg_comment_title" />
    </p>
    <p class="comment-form-comment">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label> 
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required="required"></textarea> 
    </p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment" />
</form>
```

Comment: where is this code located? And where is the code that handles your custom fields such as the `review_title`? Have you considered using the `required` flag to avoid this issue? That would fix this using pure HTML without any WordPress related changes. I'd also avoid hardcoding the URL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.